# SVG Render (Freestyle) resulting in lots of open paths

Tags: svg

[image]

I am rendering this design in Blender that is made of lots of Circles. Need to export it out to Illustrator, but realizing the resulting artworks having all open Circle path. Wonder if this is a known issue and if there is any option to toggle it?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe if you posted also Blender's settings used someone could help you to fix something there. Nothing here explains how you rendered that design.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is one operations in Adobe Illustrator that "OUTLINE" the whole line art illustration. So that should be ok. But I think Blender output of SVG is a bit dodgy.